# Looking for best practices to test stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing

We use sql server 2008 and my boss insist on testing stored procedures.

What is the best practice on testing stored procedures?
Do you use any tools ?
what is your approach?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unit testing with a framework like [DbUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) and [DbFit](http://benilovj.github.com/dbfit/) is invaluable.  Having the discipline to test means also knowing what the before and after data should be, encoding tests for edge cases when you find bugs and so on.

We keep a database available in dev that contains idealised test output data for comparing data sets with in the main dev database.  Helps to write the tests.